# Make view move when text view resigns as first responder (loses focus)

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code below moves the view when a text field resigns, but when I change it to use a text view, I get an error on the indicated line.

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y  200., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);//throws error Expected ')'

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Can anyone spot source of error? (For the record, very similar code for `textViewDidBeginEditing:` does not throw an error.)

The following also does not cause an error:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -200., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: You have to scroll over to the right it is commented out: //throws error Expected ')'

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The error is probably related to the "`200.`" after `self.view.frame.origin.y`.  Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: The 200 is the number of pixels it jumps.  textViewDidBeginEditing has -200.  At least with the textfield version, the amount of jump changes when you change number.

Comment: But there isn't an operator there.  And I don't think the period is fine either.

Comment: I'll post textViewDidBeginEditing which looks identical to me but does not throw error.

Comment: `self.view.frame.origin.y  200.` is not correct syntax. If you mean `+ 200` you need to say `+ 200` not give two numbers for the same parameter. How on earth should ObjC know what you want there. It is not php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a plus sign!

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y  200., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

should be:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + 200., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Without the plus, the compiler sees `self.view.frame.origin.y` and `200`, but doesn't know what to do with them.  The `+` tells it to add them together and pass the result into the function.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!